# Отобразить специальный элемент с LinkedList

Tags: c, list

Работаю с методом, который отобразит только одну машину по ее регистрационному номеру.
Моя структура:

```
struct car { 
    char registration[10]; 
    char model[30]; 
    char colour[30]; 
    int num; 
    bool reserved; 
    long amount; 
};

struct LinearNode {
    struct car *element;
    struct LinearNode *next;

};
```

Вызываю метод в меню следующим образом:

```
char reg[10];
printf("Input car registration:"); 
scanf("%s", reg); 
viewSpecificNodes(reg);
```

И далее сам метод:

```
void viewSpecificNodes(char *reg) {
int string;
struct LinearNode *current, *previous;
bool notFound = true;
if (isEmpty())
    printf("Error - there are no cars in the list\n");
else {
    current = front;
    while (current != NULL)

    {
        string = strcmp(reg, current->element->registration);
        if (string = 0){

                printf("Registration: %s\n", current->element->registration);
                printf("Model: %s\n", current->element->model);
                printf("Colour: %s\n", current->element->colour);
                printf("Number of previous owners: %d\n", current->element->num);

            if(current->element->reserved==0){
            printf("Car is unreserved\n");
            }else{
                printf("Car is reserved\n");
            }
                printf("Reserve amount: %li\n", current->element->amount);
        }
        else {
            printf("This car does not exist");
        }
```

current = current->next;
        }
    }
} //end viewSpecificNode

Я решила, что моя строка `string == 0` несет ошибку, потому что в самом начале у меня следующее выражение:

```
#define bool int  //defining my own verion of boolean
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

и поменяла строчку на `string == 1`. В итоге ничего роли не играет.

Этот метод просто не работает и ничего не вызывает.

Comment: После обновления кода осталась проблема с зацикливанием - проще убрать последний else. Появилось еще одна: не хватает } закрывающей for. Хотя сам цикл for здесь не нужен, т.к. вряд ли надо один элемент выводить SIZE раз, скорее, задумывалось нумеровать найденные элементы или выводить порядковый номер найденого элемента в списке.

Comment: Скорее задумка была нумеровать найденные элементы. Спасибо, проблему со скобкой сейчас исправлю

Comment: В строке if (string = 0) наверное было предупреждение - присваивание вместо сравнения. Потому и не работает сравнение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главная проблема - не инициализирован указатель current (ему не присвоен указатель на первый элемент списка **до цикла**), поэтому либо цикл не работает, либо идет по мусорным значениям (и на экране мусор, возможен сегфолт).

Замечание @Harry по поводу переменной reg весьма справедливо, но когда эту ошибку исправите, функция зависнет на первом найденном элементе (нет перехода к следующему). Что касается i - это действительно "по мелочи", на работоспособность функции не влияет, но очень некрасиво.

Comment: Да, слона-то я и не приметил :) Или - леса за деревьями... Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Я исправила свои недочеты. Теперь видимо ошибка в том, что я неправильно использую переменную reg . Но я хочу, чтобы  reg была не одним символом, а целой строчкой из символов, поэтому использую  scanf("%s", reg).

Comment: Думаю с моей функцией проблем нет. Просто я не правильно  pass a variable - reg

Answer (score 2):

Как объявлена переменная `reg` здесь: `scanf("%s", reg);`? Судя по тому, что `void viewSpecificNodes(char reg)` - это просто `char`? Но если вы хотите считывать один символ (из кода непонятно, структура `LinearNode` у вас не описана) - то надо `scanf("%c",&reg)`.

Ну, а по мелочи - переменная `i` в функции не инициализирована и не изменяется, так что когда будет выводить - выводиться в квадратных скобках будет случайный мусор, одинаковый для всех выводимых записей.

Comment: Если reg это строчка из символов, не значит ли это, что необхоимо использовать scanf("%s", reg)?

Comment: @Alex  Да, но тогда ее надо передавать в функцию как указатель на `char`, и сравнивать не с помощью оператора `==`, а `strcmp` или `stricmp`, например. А при считывании строки с помощью `scanf` могут быть неприятности, связанные с переполнением буфера. Впрочем, если это учебное задание без защиты от дураков и взломщиков, то ладно :)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую все сделать. Вы правы, задание "с защитой для дураков", поэтому стоит все проработать