# Передача параметра в функцию в C

Tags: c

В функции `main` я создаю переменную и сканирую ее следующим образом:

```
char reg[10];
printf("Input car registration number:");
scanf("%s", reg);
```

Далее в функцию я передаю ее таким образом:

```
void viewSpecificNodes(char reg) {
```

Попробовала с `reg` c `*` и программа зависла. Мне кажется, проблема в том, что я неправильно передаю переменную, потому что программа не доходит до этой функции - `void viewSpecificNodes(char reg)`

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Если программа не доходит до упомянутой функции, то проблема, вероятно, не в ней. Нужно больше кода. А про передачу параметров в любом учебнике должна быть информация. `char` - это символ. `char*` (или `char[]`) это уже массив, ну или строка, зависит от интерпретации.

Comment: Сколько символов вы считываете с помощью `scanf`? нет ли переполнения буфера? Как вы проверяете, доходит ли выполнение до `viewSpecificNodes`? Как именно вы передаете `reg` в функцию (не смейтесь, но случайно не как `*reg` или как-то еще?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Все работает](http://ideone.com/loudbN). Может ошибка в другом месте?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void viewSpecificNodes(char *reg)
{
    printf("%s", reg);
}

int main(void)
{
    char reg[10];
    scanf("%s", reg);
    viewSpecificNodes(reg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А теперь попробуйте ввод строки длиной более 10 символов :)

Comment: @alexolut А можно еще попробовать туда чушь всякую передавать с управляющими символами. А можно просто туда передавать точки, запятые и т.п. Много чего можно, но у нее это регистрационный номер автомобиля. И здесь не стоит вопрос о проверке валидности этого номера. Вопрос о передаче в функцию параметра, а не о том, что вообще можно сделать на Си.

Comment: Про валидность номера речи и не было. Речь о выходе за пределы массива и наступлении UB.

Comment: @alexolut А я разве написал, что здесь речь о валидности номера? А кто Вам сказал, что речь идет о выходе за пределы массива? Может у нее только по одному символу и вводится и она взяла десятикратный запас? Повторюсь, вопрос звучит "Передача параметра через функцию в си". Чувствуете разницу?

Comment: Как много у Вас вопросов, однако. Я всего лишь хочу сказать, что Ваш код не совсем удачен для демонстрации _работоспособности_, т.к. зависит от качества входных данных. Хороший код должен бы вывести ошибку, или не сделать вообще ничего, но уж точно не являться источником UB.

Comment: @alexolut Так а зачем здесь разводите холивар? У Вас же есть такая возможность написать свой ответ. И никаких вопросов не будет. Проголосуют за тот, что правильнее. Хотя топикастер появится только уже поздно вечером или рано утром и ненадолго и голосовать или отмечать она ничего не будет :)

Comment: Ответа быть не может пока, т.к. мне не совсем понятно, что у ТС происходит. Без доп.информации все ответы - не более чем предположения.

Comment: Я буду все отмечать, спасибо большое, что помогаете мне. Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться в чем у меня ошибка. Переполнения буфера точно не должно быть, поскольку я взяла [10] с запасом. Теперь перехожу к выводу, что ошибка в моей функции. Я так понимаю это это уже другая тема. Потому что функция теперь работает, но вместо того, чтобы выдавать то, что я хочу, она нонстопом печатает все значения и программа зависает.

Comment: Я понимаю, что наверное слишком много спрашиваю, но если проблема с самой функцией, а не с передачей параметра, то с функцией можно ознакомиться здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501735/Отобразить-специальный-элемент-с-linkedlist

Answer (score 1):

передается именно char *, иначе это передача ОДНОГО символа. Это раз. Во вторых, может быть передано большее кол-во байт чем в reg. Т.е следует использовать в scanf модификатор

```
scanf("%10s", reg);
```

Comment: Судя по всему надо бы `"%9s"`. Т.к. при `10` возникает [ошибка](http://ideone.com/JcjB8m). С другой стороны, `s` вроде как вообще не допускает указания поля ширины по Стандарту.